# Solve this indefinite integral, based on a volume problem

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This is making me extremelly pissed off, because I saw a similliar integral that was apparently unsolvable, and now dear prof send this in the list without any resolution or help.

The whole question is this:

*Consider the region S bounded by $y=1+\sqrt{x}e^{x^2}$, $y=1$, $x=a$ (x=a is in the right side of the Y-axis). Calculate the value of "A", so the volume of the solid generated by the rotation of S around $y=1$ be equal to $2\pi$.*

Comment: I believe it is unsolvable, maybe it is a mistyping?

Comment: I will edit and put the whole question, just a sec...

Comment: the integral you list has nothing to do with the volume calculation.

Comment: But, you have to solve the integral to calculate the volume... Something like $\int \pi(1+\sqrt{x}e^{x^2)^2}dx$

Comment: In calculus books in English, volumes of rotation (or "revolution" ) come under two slightly different techniques, the "disk method" and the "shell method." Look those up. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration    and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration

Comment: If you use the disk method you have to solve the integral listed above. Aparrently, same for shell method.

Comment: Not quite. You need to be a good deal more careful about all aspects of this.

Comment: Oh, well. Put another way: by not looking anything up and by being careless, you have taken a problem that is set up to be fairly easy in actuality, then produced a few impossible variations, then, according to your words, gotten angry.

Comment: I got angry by another reasons, forget, it's solved.

Comment: On a more positive note, my favorite teacher in high school used to make up songs for us; the one that fits here is "Just attention to the details and you'll get more problems right." He used the tunes of existing songs. Also played trumpet sometimes.

Comment: I agree that is good for learning the use of exercises with increasing difficult (that is not the case here) but you need some orientation or the actual answer so you can learn by your mistakes. But Brazil sucks and so is the university here, and I got to come to this forums and sites to get my things done. Anyway, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Since $V=\int_0^a\pi(\sqrt{x}e^{x^2})^2\;dx=\pi\int_0^a x e^{2x^2}\;dx=\pi[\frac{1}{4}e^{2x^2}]_0^a=\frac{\pi}{4}(e^{2a^2}-1)=2\pi$,

$e^{2a^2}=9$ so $2a^2=\ln9=2\ln3\implies a^2=\ln3\implies a=\sqrt{\ln 3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $\int_0^a\pi(1+\sqrt{x}e^{x^2})^2dx$?

Comment: @JoãoPedro, one of the boundaries comes from $y=1.$ It says that in the full problem

Comment: Yeyeye sorry bout that